# Передача текстового сообщения с отложенным чтением

Tags: delphi

Здравствуйте, обитатели и просто очень умные люди с этого сайта. У меня возникла проблема с написанием кода на делфи ... не могу написать часть программы для передачи текстового сообщения с отложенным чтением. Сама программа клиента и сервера - я её написал ...

Comment: Подробнее, пожалуйста. Кто, в какой момент и откуда должен читать ?

Comment: avp: если сервер работает а клиент отключен то написав сообщение клиенту создается временная папка и текстовый файл в который помещается сообщение после того как клиент появляется в сети то текст из файла передается клиенту а временный файл удаляется 

Comment: А в чем проблема?

Сразу после загрузки клиент отправляет на сервер запрос на получение сообщений, которые не были доставлены. Сервер ищет сообщения для этого пользователя. Передает их клиенту и помечает их, что они уже прочитаны. Все.

Comment: эээ .. проблема в том что я не могу понять как написать кож на это дело ...я не представляю что в него должно входить ((( 


Answer (score 3):

на КЛИЕНТЕ описываем процедуру Send отправки сообщения Sender - тот, кто отправляет (например номер пользователя), Message - само сообщение

```
procedure Send(Sender : integer; Message : string); 
begin
    //отправка данных серверу 
    //например строка в таком формате:
    //"From=" + IntToStr(Sender) + "#Mes=" + Message;
end;
```

на СЕРВЕРЕ описываем процедуру Send отправки сообщения Receiver - тот, кто получет сообщение(например номер пользователя), Message - само сообщение

```
procedure Send(Receiver : integer; Message : string); 
begin
    //отправка данных клиенту
    //например строка в таком формате:
    //"To=" + IntToStr(Receiver) + "#Mes=" + Message;
end;
```

на СЕРВЕРЕ описываем функцию Accept получения сообщения **Source** и его обработки.
она возврашает само сообщение и в аргумент **From** - номер пользователя-отправителя

```
function Accept(Source : string; var From : integer) : string;
begin
    //получение текста сообщения и запись его в Source например из Socket.
    From := copy(Source, 6, pos('#', Source) - 6);
    delete(Source, 1, pos('#', Source) + 4); //+4 - нужно игнорировать "Mes=" и символ "#" - разделитель и всё что до него
    Result := Source;
end;
```

на **КЛИЕНТЕ**

процедура, которая выполняется сразу после входа в чат (или что у Вас там?) 
**UserId** - идентификационный номер пользователя:

```
procedure Init(UserId : integer);
begin
    Send(UserId, "loggedIn"); //процедура осведомляет сервер, чот пользователь он-лайн
end;
```

процедура обработки полученного сообщения на **СЕРВЕРЕ**

```
procedure ProcessRequest(From : integer; Message : string);
begin
    if (Message = "loggedIn") then begin
        //сканирование папки с временными файлами - сообщениями для пользователя From. **n** - количество сообщений. запись сообщений в массив messages
        for i := 1 to n do begin
             Send(From, messages[i]);
        end;
    end else
    .... //другие случаи отправленных сообщений
end;
```

ну а **КЛИЕНТ** получает сообщения от сервера как обычно (ничего модифицировать не надо).

Comment: огромное спасибо))) за помощь) 


Answer (score 0):

Можно вообще всегда иметь для каждого клиента папку. Передаваемые сообщения записываются в файлы в в ней. Если клиент онлайн, сервер оповещает его о новом сообщении. Пусть клиент читает (передавая команды серверу) файлы оттуда и сам (посредством сервера) удаляет их.

Все упрощается.

Comment: извеняюсь за очень нескромную просьбу а можно это как то показать наглядней ? 
если так возможно фрагментом кода 

Comment: Ну, кода к сожалению нет, это предложение так, сразу, из головы. Но в целом можете посмотреть на почтовые протоколы (POP IMAP), но оповещений в них по моему нет.